# SQL Insert Into with HTML <p> tag

Tags: php, html, str-replace

I have a text field that inserts its content into an SQL table. Often, I will want this content to have `<p>` html tags within, based on line breaks in the text field. I have tried doing a replace before inserting:

```
str_replace("</p><p>", "\n", $_POST["body"]);
```

and I have tried doing a replace with escape characters:

```
str_replace("&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;", "\n", $_POST["body"]);
```

with no success. Meaning they still appear as text field line breaks. There is no security issue as the field can only be accessed by an administrator. Thank you for your help.

Comment: with no success? what's your problem

Comment: If you're trying to replace newlines with `</p><p>`, you have your parameters backwards. Also, `str_replace()` returns the string with replacements, so make sure you're setting the return value to some variable.

Comment: maybe you can find the answer here (similar question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041136/wrap-text-in-p-tag

Comment: @jprofitt found my embarrassing problem... I just had the parameters flipped. Sorry about that.

Comment: @ConnorNeville : Since your question cannot help anyone in the future, please delete it.

Comment: Also consider using `<br>`'s instead of `<p>`: [php nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems both times you are trying to replace contrary - a `</p><p>` to `\n` which obviously fails
try to swap str_replace argumants.

I don't understand what SQL has to do here though

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing each separately?

```
str_replace(array("</p>", "<p>"), array("\n","\n"), $_POST["body"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in **"** latter, like `<a href="http://google.com">google</a>`, try replacing it with **'** or call function addslashes() on your text.