# new line to <p> in php

Tags: php, nl2br

I currently have a lot of jokes in a database that are formated with nl2br() which produces...

```
This is just dummy text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<br /><br />
Vestibulum gravida justo in arcu mattis lacinia. Mauris aliquet mi quis diam euismod blandit ultricies ac lacus.
<br /><br />
Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec sed nisi ac velit viverra hendrerit.
<br />
Praesent molestie augue ligula, quis accumsan libero.
```

I need a php function that rather convert `<br /><br />` into a `<p></p>` and if there is only 1 `<br />` then leave it alone. Also trim any whitespace

So the end result would be...

```
<p>This is just dummy text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>Vestibulum gravida justo in arcu mattis lacinia. Mauris aliquet mi quis diam euismod blandit ultricies ac lacus. </p>
Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec sed nisi ac velit viverra hendrerit.<br />
Praesent molestie augue ligula, quis accumsan libero.
```

can someone point me in the right direction or give me an simple function that does this? thanks

Comment: You want to trim each row?

Answer (score 11):

Use PHP's string replace function to replace all `<br /><br />` with `</p><p>`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Sample Code:

```
$stringWithBRs = nl2br($originalString)
$stringWithPs = str_replace("<br /><br />", "</p>\n<p>", $stringWithBRs);
$stringWithPs = "<p>" . $stringWithPs . "</p>";
```

Or, you can use the following code without even calling the nl2br() function.

```
$stringWithPs = str_replace("\n\n", "</p>\n<p>", $originalString);
$stringWithPs = "<p>" . $stringWithPs . "</p>";
```

Comment: he wants to put string into <p> tags =)

Comment: Yea, its the same thing. He can replace all the `<br /><br />` with `</p><p>` and then wrap the whole text with a `<p>` and `<\p>

Answer (score 3):

Simply direct convert the original string:

```
$text=str_replace("<br /><br />", "</p><p>", $original_string);
```

And in HTML, somewhere like this:

```
<p>
 <?php echo $text; ?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

A one-liner:

```
$sNewString = implode('</p><p>',explode('<br /><br />', nl2br($sOriginalString)))
```

Explanation:

1. Convert line breaks to br's
2. Split string into array by these br's
3. Glue the array back to a string by sticking P tags between each array item

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   function nl2p($string = '') {
        $array = explode("\n", $string);
        $content = '';
        foreach ($array as $str) {
            $content .= "<p>" . $str . "</p>";
        }
        return $content;
    }
```

echo nl2p($content);

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answers, my code which generates the correct html with the p tags enclosed:

```html
$text = nl2br($text);
$text = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $text));
$text = str_replace("<br /> <br />", "<br /><br />", $text);      
$text = implode('</p><p>',explode('<br /><br />', $text));
$text = '<p>'.$text.'</p>';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$new = '';
foreach(explode("\n<br /><br />\n", $text) as $p) // split by double newlines
    $new.= "<p>$p</p>\n"; // and convert each part to a paragraph


// or if you want to keep it in a single line
$new = join(array_map(function($p){return "<p>$p</p>\n";}, explode("\n<br /><br />\n", $text)));
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try it**

```
$old_string = preg_replace("/[\r\n]/","</p><p>",$old_string);
$new_string = "<p>" . $old_string . "</p>";
echo $new_string;
```