# Replace line breaks with <p> tags

Tags: php

I've got a form with a textarea and I want to change the linebreaks from the input into paragraphs (using the `<p>` tag). I'm using explode and implode to replace `\n` with `</p><p>`, but if you have two line breaks in a row, you end up with `</p><p></p><p>`. I'm trying to use a foreach loop to go through each element and check if it it's empty to combat this, but it doesn't seem to be working at all. Here's what I have:

```
foreach($text as $value){
    if($value!=''){
        $newtext.='</p><p>'.$value;
    }
}
```

That still gives `</p><p></p><p>` for things that are double spaced. I also tried replacing `if($value!='')` with `!is_null(trim($value))` and it still didn't work. What is wrong with my code, and how can I fix it?

Comment: There's a function that adds `<br>` tags, [`nl2br`](http://au1.php.net/nl2br), which might be adequate. If you want to get the `<p>` tags, you'll need to split at newlines and wrap those chunks in `<p>...</p>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
$newtext = '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', array_filter(explode("\n", $textarea))) . '</p>';
```

1. create array by splitting on linebreaks `\n`
2. filter out empty elements
3. join together with `p` tags

Answer (score 4):

A simple method is to use [`preg_split()`](https://www.php.net/preg_split) to get an array of paragraphs:

```
$paragraphs = preg_split('/\n+/', $yourString);
```

And then echo them out wrapped in `<p>`:

```
foreach($paragraphs as $p)
{
    if(strlen($p) > 0)
    {
        echo "<p>$p</p>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function text2paragraph( $text ){
    
    $array =  explode("\n", $text);
    

    foreach($array as $element){
        if( strlen($element) > 1){
            $tagged .= '<p>'.$element.'</p>';
            
        }
    }
    return $tagged;
}
```

split text to array on "\n";

through foreach add 'p' tags;

check if 'p' element is not empty (in case of empty element, remove it);

return tagged text;